# Unable to set div margin-top

Tags: css, html, margin

I tried the following `html` code (an example from `w3schools` site):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width:500px">
            <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
                <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
                <b>Menu</b><br />
                HTML<br />
                CSS<br />
                JavaScript
            </div>
            <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
                Content goes here
            </div>
            <div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;margin-top:20px">
                Copyright © W3Schools.com
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I need to add a space between the sections `#footer` and `#content`, and as you can see I tried using the `margin-top` attribute, but any value I use (in my example `20px`) does not change the result: there is no space between the two sections.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I wonder if the "clear:both;" is interfering with the margin behavior.

Comment: Please be very careful with W3Schools.com, it's notorious for it's bugs and bad practices (see [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)). The example uses inline styles for example which isn't the best way to learn HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Costa yes (see my comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/23156644/1395740), but I can't understand how...

Comment: Me neither, floats and clears confuse my brain. I use display: inline-block instead of floats as often as I can. The only challenge with it is whitespace, which I solve by stripping it out of my html files (using jade or any other template enigne).

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why floats suck as much as they rock.

You can add an empty div in between the footer and the content like...

```
 //content html
 <div style='clear:both;'></div>
 //footer html
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rK5zV/1/

Or you can make the footer a float also with a width of 100% like...

http://jsfiddle.net/7KZy9/

Other solutions can be found here...

[Why top margin of html element is ignored after floated element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883414/why-top-margin-of-html-element-is-ignored-after-floated-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can add to content margin-bottom:20px;

```
<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;margin-bottom: 20px;">
```

Comment: Well, your solution works only if I maintain `clear:both` as `#footer` style attribute, can you explain why? And can you say why `margin-top` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can place all your elements apart from the footer in a wrapper that has `margin-bottom: 20px`:

```
<body>

    <div id="container" style="width:500px">

        <div id="wrapper" style="margin-bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; float: left;">
            <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
                <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
                <b>Menu</b><br>
                HTML<br>
                CSS<br>
                JavaScript
            </div>

            <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
                Content goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
            Copyright © W3Schools.com
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Raibaz/EmxdH/) is a jsFiddle that demonstrates the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I gave your footer relative positioning and used the top attribute

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8NpMC/)

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px">
            <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
                <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
                <b>Menu</b><br />
                HTML<br />
                CSS<br />
                JavaScript
            </div>
            <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
                Content goes here
            </div>
            <div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:left;text-align:center;position:relative;top:20px">
                Copyright © W3Schools.com
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making footer `display: inline-block; width: 100%`. It's not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

After two blocks with styles float you should to use element with style cler:both;
You code view like this

```
<div id="content">
  ...
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="footer">
  ...
</div>
```