# Why the top & bottom padding comes to floated element?

Tags: html, css, css-float

One doubt:

I give float:left for the div and put another block element such as h3 inside the div. Then it gives padding top and bottom. If i remove float: left it wont give padding.

**html**

```
<div class="one"><h3>Test with Float</h3></div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="two"><h3>Test without Float</h3></div>
```

**css**

```
.one{
    background: grey;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}
.two{
    background: #DAD5C1;
      width: 100%;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7yh3kuea/

Comment: Please put your code in the question or don't bother linking to the fiddle at all. Don't circumvent the quality filter.

Comment: bad way to asking, but interesting question.

Comment: thanks  rnrneverdies

Answer (score 0):

It isn't padding but it is margin which is ignored in no-floated element.

More informations is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883414/why-top-margin-of-html-element-is-ignored-after-floated-element).

Comment: sorry, i have seen this link already. but not understand well.