# Height of heading element is more than expected

Tags: html, css, margin

I've got this html here:

```css
    #books {
        margin-top: 4rem;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 well">
        <h1 class="text-center">Brian Jacques</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center"><i>The scribe who was an abbot to all his readers</i></h3>
        <figure class="figure col-lg-12">
          <div class="img-thumbnail col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <img src="http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah88/ejacobosaur/Brian%20Jacques%20Cartoonized_zpsz412eynr.jpg" class="img-responsive figure-img img-fluid" alt="Brian Jacques cartoon">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Jacques smiling. A radiance that shines through his books. Painted by Derek Wehrwein. </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
    
        <h2 class="text-center" id="books">Widely Known For
        </h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redwall" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button" target="_blank">Redwall</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castaways_of_the_Flying_Dutchman" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button" target="_blank">Castaways of the Flying Dutchman</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <blockquote>
      <p class="text-center lead"><em>"So here is my story, may it bring<br>Some smiles and a tear or so,<br>It happened once upon a time,<br>Far away, and long ago,<br>Outside the night wind keens and wails,<br>Come listen to me, the Teller of Tales!"</em></p>
      <footer class="text-center">Brian Jacques,<cite title="Lord Brocktree"> Lord Brocktree</cite></footer>

        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The part concerning my question is the h2 tag that is directly under the closing figure tag and has the text "Widely Know For".

I've been trying to add top margin to this element (h2) but have had no success. When I opened it up in debugger mode and select this element, it shows that its height extends almost to the top of the page instead of to the bottom of the element above it (figure).

Just to see, I took out this h2 element so that the div under it took its place. This div did not have the same problem. It had a normal height and I was able to add a top margin to it just fine.

It seems to be just the heading tag that has this problem.

I'm thinking the issue has to do with the html in some way but I have no idea why.

Here's the link to the codepen:http://codepen.io/edsonmendieta/pen/jqjRry

Help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

[image: Screenshot of issue in debugger mode]

Comment: Your fiddle does not contain the id `books` to the `h2` per your css above. Add that and it works - https://jsfiddle.net/3s3za2g1/1/

Comment: like @isherwood said I don't see any issue [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2er5ujy6/)

Comment: @isherwood I accidentally deleted your fiddle thinking it was my link for some reason. Yeah, the problem doesn't occur. I'm using Codepen, so I'm guessing the issue is not the code but how Codepen is displaying it.

Comment: Anyone ever hear about these types of issues in Codepen?

Comment: @isherwood: Yes, I know. Looking at their fiddle, I just suspected that the Op might be styling using the id selector, but forgot to specify the id to the element in the code.

Comment: @all - Thanks guys for your help, it seems to be just a false bug as a result of the way it's displayed in Codepen.  

In these situations does the OP delete the question?

Comment: It's not. See my answer.

Comment: @all - Jk, there was an issue and now it's fixed. Thanks guys for the help and sorry for any confusion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're following a floated element. You'll need to apply one technique or another to clear the float. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883414/why-top-margin-of-html-element-is-ignored-after-floated-element).

The simplest option is probably to use Bootstrap's built-in clearing class:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<h2 class="text-center" id="books">Widely Known For</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap class `.col-lg-12` which the `figure` above your `h2` has, has `float: left;`. Floated elements are not calculated into the parent element 's height.

Remove that class from the `figure` element - this will fix it and let you change the top margin and distance of your `h2` element.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwVdPO

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for me. Using the .clearfix bootstrap class in a div before the h2 tag solved the issue though, but thanks for your help.