# How can I keep an element under a floated one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.one, .two{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.one{
  float:left;
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}

.two{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">something</div>
<div class="two">something else</div>
```

As you can see both elements are next to each other. While I want to keep them under each other. I mean the `div.two` should be on the bottom of `div.one`. Noted that `div.one` should have `float:left` property *(I cannot remove it)*.

Also both `clear:both` and `display:block` doesn't work as expected. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: here is some easy reading about float behaviors and how to deal with it https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 3):

Just add clear to the second div, see below

```css
.one, .two{
  border: 1px solid;
}

.one{
  float:left;
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}

.two{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">something</div>
<div class="two">something else</div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you .. upvote. Just another related question. Why `margin-too: 5px;` on `div.two` doesn't apply?

Comment: `margin-too` is supposed to be `margin-top`

Comment: @Sushanth-- Well yes, I meant that. But it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/dgwbvxuk/

Comment: @martin, after you float something it is no longer used to find the margin by the element below that. You can find proper explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883414/why-top-margin-of-html-element-is-ignored-after-floated-element

Comment: @MartinAJ Check the possible solution I have posted below.

Comment: You could add to your answers a few others ways to clear the float aside the width:100% `overflow, float, display(s)`, It will help the op understands what's going on with float and how to deal with or mind them when used ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** layout for this use case. Margin also plays pretty well with this and lot more flexible than using `floated` elements.

```css
.one,
.two {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.one {
  align-self: baseline;
}

.two {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 125px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">something</div>
  <div class="two">something else</div>
</div>
```

You just have a parent container that acts as the flex container and the 2 divs act as their children.