# CSS div margin ignored

Tags: css

I was practising positioning divs by CSS and I found out margin of div being ignored. I cannot understand why `margin-top` of `b2` is being ignored.
When I modified `margin-bottom` of `b1`, there was a space between two divs.

```css
.b1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.b2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why top margin of html element is ignored after floated element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883414/why-top-margin-of-html-element-is-ignored-after-floated-element)

Comment: You don't need to use float now. Use FLEXBOX, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or for more complicated grid layout use GRID, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that only one of the `div`s had the float property. If you add `float: left;` to `.b2` then it works as expected.

```css
.b1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.b2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
```